# Cluttering lic files after migrating csproj files to sdk style

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csproj, mindscape

I am migrating some csproj files from the old style to the new SDK style for an old solution.After migrating, I found some lic files appearing within the projects, which were not seen in the solution explorer before. Take one project for instance:

[image: cuttering lic files found in project]

When I inspect the properties of the file, it looks like this:
[image: properties of a lic file]

My question is: why do they appear in the solution explorer after migrating the csproj file? Is there a way to "hide" them so that the solution explorer doesn't look so cluttered?

Comment: These seem to be license files for that Mindscape library your're using. You could try adding a `<None Remove="Mindscape.*.lic" />` to that project's csproj, however I'm not entirely sure whether this breaks some license validation stuff of the library. As to why these files are included: the new csproj format includes most stuff by default, so the project file isn't cluttered with explicit includes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your original wpf program contains various third-party components, and each component has a corresponding license file in the bin folder, but you may omit the bin folder during the migration process, resulting in .lic The file appears in solution explorer. This is the .lic file you see.

Since you didn't provide the format of your csproj file migration, if you make sure it's correct right click on the .lic file and click properties, then set Copy to output directory to Copy Always. Finally rebuild the project.

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean by "providing the format of your csproj file migration"? Can you please give an example/elaborate so I can add further information?

Comment: @tmsh This refers to your csproj file. Setting copy to output directory to always copy doesn't solve your issue?

Comment: unfortunately, setting copy to output directory to "always copy" didn't solve this problem. @wenbingeng-msft

Comment: @tmsh Can you share your CSPROJ file format?